# Track when file is added to SharePoint subfolders in Power Automate Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

In Power Automate Cloud, would like to track every change in all subdirectories of a given directory that is not the root directory of a SharePoint site.

Thought of using [`When a file is created or modified (properties only)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-a-file-is-created-or-modified-(properties-only)) however when specifying the parent `Folder` it doesn't track changes in the subdirectories.

A [workaround for that](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/When-a-file-is-created-or-modified-properties-only-not-tracking/m-p/519568/highlight/true#M66384) is to leave the `Folder` blank. However, if one writes a lot to a given SharePoint site, the flow would be triggered constantly, and that is not a satisfiable solution.

[image]

Thought of:

- Creating a new SharePoint Site just for this specific query.
- Having multiple flows, one to track changes in each subdirectory.

But both options seem like an overkill.

How can one track, in Power Automate Cloud, when a file is added in all subdirectories of a given directory in SharePoint?